# compiling with gcc 4.9.2 , strange error about "not in executable format"

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, gdb

When using gcc4.9.2 to compile an app, I get a strange error when attempting to debug with gdb. Although I can run the executable OK:

```
$./simapp --help

Checking for design variables is enabled.
Quick simplification of expressions is enabled.    
In expressions, the replacement of references by their values is enabled.    
Usage: simapp [options] [-r rawfile] [inputfile]

Options:
    -h             List devices and analyses.
    .............................
```

But, attempting to run through gdb gives an error about not being in executable format... why?

```
$gdb simapp
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-75.el6)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
"/home/build/64bitdebug/bin/simapp": not in executable format: File format not recognized
(gdb)
```

What's wrong with the format? Here are a few possibly relevant lines from "ldd simapp":

```
libstdc++.so.6 => /opt/gcc/4.9.2_rebld/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f4c8f119000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003e9c200000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /opt/gcc/4.9.2_rebld/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f4c8ef02000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003e9be00000)
```

Edit Note: I realized this executable is ~800MB; is there some kind of size limit on the executable?

Comment: You should upgrade your  [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). Its current version is 7.8.2, and recent `gcc` are wanting recent `gdb`

Comment: Have you tried `gdb ./simapp` ? What is output of `file ./simapp` ?

Comment: I agree with Basile - "gdb doesn't understand [all of] your executable", and a newer gdb would solve the problem.

Comment: Nope, but that was certainly a good idea:

GNU gdb (GDB) 7.8.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details..
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
"opt/path/bin/simapp": not in executable format: File format not recognized
(gdb) 

Note: I realized this executable is ~800MB; is there a size limit?

Comment: file ./simapp is questionable:

$file ./simapp
./simapp: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped

$file ./simgui
./simgui: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped

Comment: You could try compiling with `gcc -gdwarf-2` for more compatibility with older gdb.

Comment: what command line did you use to compile the simapp file?  did you use the -g and -gdb compile/link parameters?

Comment: perhaps I'm misunderstanding something, but why is the OP comment discussing file simgui rather than file simapp?

Comment: If I were trying to debug this I would try building an even more recent (perhaps git master) gdb and use --enable-targets=all.  I'd also try it on a trivial test program compiled with the same compiler; and if that failed, I would file a bug report.